# How to automatically resize text to have it fit a label in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, text, resize, label

I have a label that currently may contain words between 6 and x characters in length? However, when the word becomes too large, I want the text to change sizes so that it fits in the same amount of space. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
        Label1.Size = New Size(ClientSize.Width / 3, ClientSize.Height / 3)
        Label1.Font = New Font("Arial", ClientSize.Height / 20)
    End Sub
```